# Retrieving file encoding in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to process a folder full of data files of various formats and encodings. I no that building a generic process will require plenty of extreme cases to cover, but I do want to be able to address most files and folders.
To address unknown encodings, I ran `file -I *.csv` on 4-5 sample folders to curate a list of the most common encodings. I then iterate the list in order to "guess" the right encoding for a certain file. Below is my code:

```
    CSV_delimiter = ','
    _encodings = ["us-ascii", "utf-8", "binary", "utf-16le"]
    try:
        for e in _encodings:
            try:
                df = pd.read_excel(filepath, dtype=str) if '.xlsx' in \
                      filepath else pd.read_csv(filepath, dtype=str, low_memory=False, 
                      error_bad_lines=True, sep=CSV_delimiter, encoding=e)
                break
            except:
                continue
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Put efficiency aside, I have two issues with the block currently:

1. I will never cover all possible encodings, nor want to iterate through a big list. Ideally i'd use a python equivalent of `file -I *.csv`, and for each file use the relevant encoding.  What is the best way to implement it?
2. I noticed that some files look like csv, but they are not really. For this folder of data:
   [image]
   my script failed in the text/plain files, albeit they are formatted as csv and have a csv extension. An guesses?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `chardet` to detect the file encodings, something like:

```py
import chardet

try:
    if '.xlsx' in filepath:
        df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
    else:
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
            encoding = chardet.detect(f.read(10000)).get('encoding')

        if encoding is not None:
            df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding=encoding)
        else:
            print(f'Unknown encoding: {filepath}')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```